# How to get the list of azure servers having Auto-Shutdown disabled using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-rm

I want to get the list of azure servers having auto-shutdown disabled on them, I have the below script but the issue with the script is that it gets the list of RG's under the Subscription GUID but repeats the output after every loop.

```
Import-AzureRmContext -Path "$PSScriptRoot\AzureProfile.json"

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId {subscriptionId}


[array]$ResourceGroupArray = Get-AzureRMVm | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName, Name, VmId
   
foreach ($resourceGroup in $ResourceGroupArray){
    $targetResourceId = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $resourceGroup.Name).Id
    $shutdownInformation = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules -Expandproperties).Properties
    Write-Host "ID: " $targetResourceId
    $shutdownInformation
```

The output for each VM is displayed in the following format,

[image]

What I want is simple, I want the VM name and its status of Auto-shutdown to be displayed on the screen so that its easy for me to find out which all VM have auto-shutdown currently disabled on them.

Any help related to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the `microsoft.devtestlab/schedules` resource ID using:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{rgName}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{vmName}
```

Then iterate over all your VMs using [`Get-AzVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-5.0.0), Get the `microsoft.devtestlab/schedules` resource using [`Get-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-5.0.0), then output VM name and status into a table using [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7).

```bsh
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

& {
    foreach ($vm in Get-AzVM) {
        try {
            $shutdownResource = Get-AzResource `
                -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-$($vm.Name)" `
                -ErrorAction Stop

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName = $vm.Name
                ShutdownStatus = $shutdownResource.Properties.status
            }
        }
        catch {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName = $vm.Name
                ShutdownStatus = $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

To set the context to the correct subscription, we can use [`Set-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-5.0.0).

The above however is using the latest `Az` modules. You can do the same using the equivalent `AzureRm` modules.

```bsh
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

& {
    foreach ($vm in Get-AzureRmVM) {
        try {
            $shutdownResource = Get-AzureRmResource `
                -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-$($vm.Name)" `
                -ErrorAction Stop

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName = $vm.Name
                ShutdownStatus = $shutdownResource.Properties.status
            }
        }
        catch {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName = $vm.Name
                ShutdownStatus = $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Although I do recommend moving to the `Az` module since support for `AzureRm` is ending December 2020. You can read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.0.0) for more information about this.

The above code should give you an output similar to the following

```
VMName    ShutdownStatus
------    --------------
vm1       Enabled
vm2       Disabled
```

---

### Update

The [Call operator &](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-) is used here to run the for loop as a script block. You can read more about this in [`about_Script_Blocks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=%20About%20Script%20Blocks%20%201%20Short%20description.,%28%20by...%205%20See%20Also.%20%20More%20).

Comment: @ RoadRunner thanks, I wanted to know what is the use of & that you have used before foreach loop? and How do I copy the output to the text file that is displayed on the console?  I tried adding set-content at the end like Format-Table -AutoSize | Set-Content C:\Output1.txt but it didn't work and then I also tried by adding the set-content after the foreach loop without format-table command and it worked but copied the content in this format @{VMName=vwmazdvag1; ShutdownStatus=Enabled}. Which has additional data in it and not simply the VM name and its status.

Comment: Also, for some of the VM I got the status as ShutdownStatus=ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-vwmazimdvdb1' under resource group 'ResourceGroupName' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix}. Any idea about this error as the RG is part of the subscription?

Comment: @SRP I've added explanation of the `&` operator. As for piping the entire output to a file, you can do `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath output.txt`. Depends on what you want the output format to be, that is not included in your question.

Comment: The *extra* information is probably from `Get-AzResource` raising an exception, whereby I put `$_.Exception.Message` to show the error message in the status. `ResourceNotFound` will happen because your VM does not have shutdown status enabled, which in itself is a `microsoft.devtestlab/schedules` resource. You can probably put something else, but putting the exception message is probably more useful to find out why the VM does not have a shutdown status.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the auto-shutdown status of all VMs. Instead of trying to get the schedules inside the loop, get all the ones in the subscription and match them based on the VM's full resource Id.

```
[array]$VMArray = Get-AzureRMVm | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName, Name, VmId, Id
$ShutdownInformation = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules -Expandproperties).Properties

foreach($vm in $VMArray) {
    $ShutdownStatus = "Not Configured"
    $Schedule = $ShutdownInformation | Where-Object { $_.targetResourceId -eq $vm.Id } | Select -First 1
    if($Schedule -ne $null) {
        $ShutdownStatus = $Schedule.status
    }

    Write-Host $vm.VmId $ShutdownStatus
}
```

Comment: @ SamaraSoucy-MSFT, I am getting this error after executing the code, Any idea? Get-AzureRmResource : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Demo3.ps1:28 char:25
+ ... ormation = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/sc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet

Comment: Take a look at your version of AzureRM- `Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRM -AllVersions`. I had to update mine to latest (6.13.1) since there was an issue in version 5 with this command.